# ASP.NET error on the default.cs

Tags: c#, html

I have my html code in the default.aspx page and I am not able to access the onclick of button event on my default.cs page. I am inheriting System.Web.UI.Page in my default.cs page. Is there any way I can get the onclick events in the .cs file

Comment: Wouldn't that file usually be called Default.aspx.cs? Does your CodeFile/CodeBehind attribute point to the right file?

Comment: If you're just starting out with coding I recommend you look at ASP.NET MVC. It's pretty much replaced WebForms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your .aspx file contains correct CodeBehind and Inherits:

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.cs" Inherits="Default" %>`

If the class of the page specified in Default.cs is within a namespace, make sure to include that into Inherits as well. Like this:

`<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.cs" Inherits="MyNamespace.Default" %>`